# "Error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'std::cin >> ((Parardha*)this)->Parardha::mobile'|"

Tags: c++

Alright..I'm a beginner and hence need help with this error.
Any help is really appreciated :)

```
    #include<iostream>
class Parardha
{
private:
    char name[20];
    int mobile[11];
public:
    void ask()
    {
        std::cout<<"Your Name Please! :";
        std::cin >> name;
        std::cout<<"Aapka Phone No. : ";
        std::cin>> mobile;
    }
    void print()
    {
        std::cout<<"Your Name is";
        std::cout<<name<< std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Aur aapka mobile number hai";
        std::cout<<mobile<< std::endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
Parardha rocks;
rocks.ask();
rocks.print();
}
```

I tried this from my guidebook and my no none seems to have any idea about C++ 11!

Comment: The member variable `mobile` is an array of different eleven integers, not a single integer with eleven digits.

Comment: There is no overload for `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, int mobile[11]);` unless you provide one yourself. Same for `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& is, const int mobile[11]);`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I am not very good at this so could you please specify what exactly I need to change? @joachimPileborg

Answer (score 0):

As Joachim Pileborg said in the comment, `mobile` is array of integers, not a integer that can hold 11 digits. 
The problem is here

```
int mobile[11];
```

Replace with

```
int mobile;
```

May be looking at array tutorials will help understand how they work.
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Since you also want only 11 digits in a phone number, what you can do is to store the mobile into string and then convert it to int.
Something like this

```
private:
    std::string name;      <-- see difference here
    std::string mobile;    <-- see difference here
public:
    void ask()
    {
       //your code
    }
    void print()
    {
        std::cout<<"Your Name is";
        std::cout<<name<< std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Aur aapka mobile number hai";
        std::istringstream sstream(mobile);    
        int cellNum;
        sstream >> cellNum;
        std::cout<<cellNum<< std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Thank You! @sam2090 and also Joachim and πάντα ῥεῖ! Grateful! :)

Comment: A slight problem with this though, especially if the OP inputs 11 digits as then the input operator will write the string-terminator out of bounds. Better use `std::string` for both `name` and `mobile` (@ParardhaSarmah)